# Вопрос с аннотацией переменной

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите, что тут может быть не так?

Comment: написано указать в аннотации tuple, а тут что указано?

Comment: что указано????

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно указывать типы данных элементов, которые будут помещены в кортеж:

```
test_data: list[tuple[int, str, bool]] = [
     (44, 'success', True),
     (16, 'failure', True),
     (4, 'success', False),
     (21, 'failure', False)
]
```

P.s. На будущее, оставляйте код в виде текста, а не картинки.